# jupyter notebooks not seen by GitHub

Tags: linux, github, virtual-machine, jupyter-notebook

I have some local jupyter notebooks in my Linux virtual machine. I would like to make a repository with them on Github. 
I downloaded Github Desktop as it seems easier than using command line.

The issue, is that when I select the file containing my notebooks (which I put on a share folder with my host OS (windows)) to add a repository, then on Github Desktop its still written '0 changed files', hence I can not commit to master. When I publish the repository, then its obviously empty :(.

Any suggestion would help me, I am new to Git.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the files to a local clone of your GitHub repository.

1. Create a repository on GitHub with the name of the project.
2. Clone project to your desktop using GitHub Desktop.
3. Move all folder contents from your share folder on Windows to the cloned repository folder in the GitHub folder, probably inside of your Documents folder.
4. Follow the prompts on the GitHub Desktop client to add files to repository. Commit changes. And push the changes to GitHub's server.

You may find it easier to read the GitHub Desktop tutorial for more information on how to use GitHub. https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing-to-projects/

Comment: I'm glad this helps. :)